# Parent listeners triggering Angular 2 iframe re-render

Tags: angular, iframe, event-handling

**EDIT:**

Looks like ANY event is causing angular to re-render the component(ancestor listeners and siblings)...is this a design intent behind ngZone and component interaction?

---

**original:**

I have a web page with an iframe running an Angular deployment.
The page (parent to the iframe running angular) looks like it has a blanket click event. I can't seem to find a way to prevent this listener from causing NgZone from triggering angular's ng directives from being evaluated every time the parent event triggers...

```
pageLoad -> 
iframeLoad -> 
routing within angular works fine -> 
component renders -> 
clickEvent (within component DOM elements) causes subscribed/observables to re-evaluate.
```

As for the angular code:

I am pulling from service `private developmentService: RestService`

onInit() subscribes to a service call `.subscribe(response => this.developmentWafers = response);`

I then use a loop `<ng-container *ngFor='let wafer of`**`getAllWafers()`**`'>` where `getAllWafers()` returns the *subscribed* result `this.developmentWafers`

---

```
getAllWafers(){
        return this.developmentWafers;
    }
```

runs ~ 3 times per each listener when iframe parent window gets click event

---

What I've tried prior to arriving to conclusion that issue is from iframe parent:

`e.stopPropagation`
`e.preventDefault`
I've tried from ngZone perspective by building custom zoning component and changed all events within iframe to be scoped within their own NameSpace